# Future timeout and IO timout

Tags: java, multithreading

I have multiple threads calling an API. API opens a socket which doesn't have timeout set on it. However, I have timeout set on future.get()..If socket is kept open forever does future's timeout come in action and get out of the processing of task which calls an API ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Future.get` will throw a `TimeoutException` when the timeout expires.

Yet, the underlying task will keep executing unless you have a way to interrupt it. It can be for instance by closing the socket if you have access to it or by any mechanism that the API provides.

You can try to interrupt the execution but it is up to code to catch the interruption (via `Thread.interrupted()`) so it may have no effect depending on the underlying task implementation:

```
try {
    Future<R> future = // ... 
} catch (TimeoutException e) {
    // ...
    future.cancel(true); // try to interrupt
}
```

Comment: When Future throws TimeoutException, does thread stop ? Or it will just wait for underlying task to finish ? Also, is there any mechanism on future's side or any other(apart from what you have mentioned already) for that sake to interrupt underlying IO operation ?

Comment: No because it is the responsibility of the task to know what to do when it is interrupted. Or provide an interruption mechanism if necessary. It could have undesirable side effects otherwise.

Comment: So thread will hang in forever if underlying task is not interrupted ?

Comment: If you have no way of interrupting it, yes. You can test on simple examples with like a ``while(true)`` loop

Comment: Thanks for the response Jean ! :-)